# How to identify a character position that may be either letters or underscore

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to cleanse strings in a table that might be polluted in head. the unwanted character will be in many characters and some common may appear between valid characters, while the valid string starts with `[0-9a-zA-Z]`,`\[\]`and underscore but may contain other chars after, like `#@ This_is_.a_[cat]^`, `' __process_'data'#`. How to identify the start position of my valid string?

The ways like

`WHILE LEN(@str) > 1
IF PATINDEX([0-9a-zA-Z\[\]_]%, @str) = 0
@str = SUBSTRING(@str,2,999)
ELSE
--find valid head`

or something like `PATINDEX([0-9a-zA-Z\[\]_]% ESCAPE _, @str)`,

`PATINDEX([0-9a-zA-Z\[\]_]% ESCAPE [_], @str)`,

`PATINDEX([0-9a-zA-Z\[\][_]]%, @str)`

doesn't work (PATINDEX always = 0).

Comment: can you add some examples: input string and the expected value after cleansing?

Comment: @Julien Vavasseur for e.g. ` ' __process_'data'#` works as `__process_'data'#`, `. $$@@      #123_456` should become `123_456`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the function `PATINDEX`, but if you check each character with `CHARINDEX` until you found one that's allowed at the beginning of your string, it should work. Try this for example:

```
DECLARE @Str nvarchar(50) = N'"§$"!This is your text or column or whatever';
DECLARE @AllowStart nvarchar(100) = N'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]_'; -- All characters which are allowed at the beginning
DECLARE @Index int = 1;
WHILE @Index <= LEN(@Str)
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@Str, @Index, 1), @AllowStart) > 0 -- Test if character at position @Index is part of @AllowStart
        BREAK;

    SET @Index += 1;
END

SET @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str, @Index, 100);
```

Comment: Well, its wonderful to solve this problem by 'reverse' using `CHARINDEX`!

Comment: You don't need @ EndLoop. It can be replace by Break. SET @ Str = SUBSTRING can be done outside of the loop once you break from it.